# bind_cols into a data frame and keep named numeric names

Tags: r

I have 4 very short lists and I want to bind them together into a single data frame. I have tried `bind_cols(x)` where `x` is the list. I have also tried `lapply(x, data.frame) %>% bind_cols()`.

They both create the list but I lose the names.

Desired output:

```
Var Name      ....1     ....2     ....3     ....4
Accuracy    0.8690265 0.8103582 0.7820126 0.7598878
Sensitivity 0.7336562 0.7589099 0.7877551 0.7327766
Specificity 0.8848108 0.8175676 0.7811213 0.7640959
Precision   0.4261603 0.3682604 0.3584030 0.3253012
F1          0.5391459 0.4958904 0.4926611 0.4505777
MCC         0.4925390 0.4352215 0.4252838 0.3688497
AUC         0.8092335 0.7882387 0.7844382 0.7484363
```

Data:

```
list(structure(c(0.869026548672566, 0.73365617433414, 0.88481084133258, 
0.426160337552743, 0.53914590747331, 0.492538999353894, 0.80923350783336
), .Dim = c(7L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("Accuracy", "Sensitivity", 
"Specificity", "Precision", "F1", "MCC", "AUC"), NULL)), structure(c(0.810358155114661, 
0.758909853249476, 0.817567567567568, 0.368260427263479, 0.495890410958904, 
0.435221475998339, 0.788238710408522), .Dim = c(7L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Accuracy", "Sensitivity", "Specificity", "Precision", 
    "F1", "MCC", "AUC"), NULL)), structure(c(0.782012613106663, 
0.787755102040816, 0.781121317706684, 0.358402971216342, 0.492661135928526, 
0.425283810027502, 0.78443820987375), .Dim = c(7L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Accuracy", "Sensitivity", "Specificity", "Precision", 
    "F1", "MCC", "AUC"), NULL)), structure(c(0.759887798036466, 
0.732776617954071, 0.764095917044718, 0.325301204819277, 0.450577663671374, 
0.368849691479186, 0.748436267499395), .Dim = c(7L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Accuracy", "Sensitivity", "Specificity", "Precision", 
    "F1", "MCC", "AUC"), NULL)))
```

EDIT:

```
> bind_cols(x) %>%
+   as.data.frame %>%
+   `row.names<-`(., row.names(x[[1]]))
  X..i.....1 X..i.....2 X..i.....3 X..i.....4
1  0.8690265  0.8103582  0.7820126  0.7598878
2  0.7336562  0.7589099  0.7877551  0.7327766
3  0.8848108  0.8175676  0.7811213  0.7640959
4  0.4261603  0.3682604  0.3584030  0.3253012
5  0.5391459  0.4958904  0.4926611  0.4505777
6  0.4925390  0.4352215  0.4252838  0.3688497
7  0.8092335  0.7882387  0.7844382  0.7484363
> 
> do.call(cbind, x)
     X..i.....1 X..i.....2 X..i.....3 X..i.....4
[1,]  0.8690265  0.8103582  0.7820126  0.7598878
[2,]  0.7336562  0.7589099  0.7877551  0.7327766
[3,]  0.8848108  0.8175676  0.7811213  0.7640959
[4,]  0.4261603  0.3682604  0.3584030  0.3253012
[5,]  0.5391459  0.4958904  0.4926611  0.4505777
[6,]  0.4925390  0.4352215  0.4252838  0.3688497
[7,]  0.8092335  0.7882387  0.7844382  0.7484363
```

EDIT 2:

Removing the line `column_to_rownames('rn')` and running:

```
map(x, ~ .x %>%
      as.data.frame %>%
      rownames_to_column('rn')) %>% 
  reduce(inner_join, by = 'rn')
```

Gives me:

```
  rn  X..i...x  X..i...y X..i...x.x X..i...y.y
1  1 0.8690265 0.8103582  0.7820126  0.7598878
2  2 0.7336562 0.7589099  0.7877551  0.7327766
3  3 0.8848108 0.8175676  0.7811213  0.7640959
4  4 0.4261603 0.3682604  0.3584030  0.3253012
5  5 0.5391459 0.4958904  0.4926611  0.4505777
6  6 0.4925390 0.4352215  0.4252838  0.3688497
7  7 0.8092335 0.7882387  0.7844382  0.7484363
```

Comment: let me check on R 3.6.1

Comment: rownames_to_column('rn') should give the the actual rownames.  Can you try `map(x, ~ rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(.x), "rn"))`

Comment: That gives me a list of 4 with the rownames now a column.

Comment: THat is good.  Now, do the `reduce` step on it `map(x, ~ rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(.x), "rn")) %>% reduce(inner_join, by = 'rn')`

Comment: That works! It gives columns `rn`, `V1.x`, `V1.y`, `V1.x.x` and `V1.y.y`.

Comment: So, i guess in one of the versions, when we do the `%>%` with `.x %>% as.data.frame` it is stripping off the actual row names

Comment: tidyverse functions generally drop rownames—there's [some debate](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/272) around that decision and it can be annoying. Seems like there's been some new options considered looking at the `tibble` reference [here](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/as_tibble.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tidyverse functions drops the row names.  So, we may have to preprocess the row names separately

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
map(x, ~ .x %>%
            as.data.frame %>%
            rownames_to_column('rn')) %>% 
    reduce(inner_join, by = 'rn') %>%
    column_to_rownames('rn')
#              V1.x      V1.y    V1.x.x    V1.y.y
#Accuracy    0.8690265 0.8103582 0.7820126 0.7598878
#Sensitivity 0.7336562 0.7589099 0.7877551 0.7327766
#Specificity 0.8848108 0.8175676 0.7811213 0.7640959
#Precision   0.4261603 0.3682604 0.3584030 0.3253012
#F1          0.5391459 0.4958904 0.4926611 0.4505777
#MCC         0.4925390 0.4352215 0.4252838 0.3688497
#AUC         0.8092335 0.7882387 0.7844382 0.7484363
```

#### Update

As there is some issues in the behavior of functions with different versions, i.e. when we do the `%>%`, it is stripping of the actual rownames with the default index.  To avoid, that do the `rownames_to_column` conversion outside the `%>%` and then do the `reduce` and the `column_to_rownames`

```
 map(x, ~ rownames_to_column(as.data.frame(.x), "rn")) %>% 
       reduce(inner_join, by = 'rn') %>%
       column_to_rownames('rn')
```

---

Or another option is

```
bind_cols(x) %>%
   as.data.frame %>%
   `row.names<-`(., row.names(x[[1]]))
#              ...1      ...2      ...3      ...4
#Accuracy    0.8690265 0.8103582 0.7820126 0.7598878
#Sensitivity 0.7336562 0.7589099 0.7877551 0.7327766
#Specificity 0.8848108 0.8175676 0.7811213 0.7640959
#Precision   0.4261603 0.3682604 0.3584030 0.3253012
#F1          0.5391459 0.4958904 0.4926611 0.4505777
#MCC         0.4925390 0.4352215 0.4252838 0.3688497
#AUC         0.8092335 0.7882387 0.7844382 0.7484363
```

---

It is more compact in `base R` though

```
do.call(cbind, x)
#               [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
#Accuracy    0.8690265 0.8103582 0.7820126 0.7598878
#Sensitivity 0.7336562 0.7589099 0.7877551 0.7327766
#Specificity 0.8848108 0.8175676 0.7811213 0.7640959
#Precision   0.4261603 0.3682604 0.3584030 0.3253012
#F1          0.5391459 0.4958904 0.4926611 0.4505777
#MCC         0.4925390 0.4352215 0.4252838 0.3688497
#AUC         0.8092335 0.7882387 0.7844382 0.7484363
```

Comment: The first option gives me the following error `Error: `df` must be a data frame without row names in `column_to_rownames()`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred`

Comment: @user113156  May be it is a clash of the versions.  Can you try the second option

Comment: Second and third options work but they don't add the row names. I added the outputs to the original post.

Comment: @user113156  For me, it is giving the row names.

Comment: @user113156  I am using `R 3.6.2` with `packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘0.8.99.9000’
> packageVersion('purrr')
[1] ‘0.3.3’` and `packageVersion('tibble')#
[1] ‘2.99.99.9012’`

Comment: I have the following packages: `dplyr_0.8.99.9000` , `purrr_0.3.3` and `tibble_2.99.99.9014`. With `R version 3.6.1`

Comment: The dplyr and purrr version seems to be same, but the R version of mine is more recent

Comment: I added a second edit. I have the problem with the line `column_to_rownames('rn')`.